# How to suppress PHP Warnings with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling, warnings

I've tried hard to by-pass PDO warning but without success.

Here's my code (file names and parameters are obfuscated with `XXXXXX`):

```
try {
    ini_set('pdo_mysql.debug' , '0');

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=XXXXXX;port=XXXXXX;dbname=XXXXXX", 'XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $pdo->exec('SET session wait_timeout=1');

    $pdo->query('SELECT 1');
    echo "SELECT 1\n";

    sleep(2);

    $pdo->query('SELECT 1');
    echo "SELECT 1\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
}
```

I've tried with and w/o `ini_set`, I've tried with PDO error mode in constuctor, in parameters or both (like in this example), I've also tried with named host or its IP address.

`SET wait_timeout` and `sleep` are here just to help testing

Nothing to do, I always get the same result:

```
SELECT 1
PHP Warning:  PDO::query(): MySQL server has gone away in XXXXXX/test.php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() XXXXXX/test.php:0
PHP   2. PDO->query() XXXXXX/test.php:19
PHP Warning:  PDO::query(): Error reading result set's header in XXXXXX/test.php on line 19
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() XXXXXX/test.php:0
PHP   2. PDO->query() XXXXXX/test.php:19
Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

As you can see, Exception has been catched (last line) and it's catched as well with catching `PDOException` or `Throwable`, with or without backslash.

I just wish to suppress PHP Warning, and normally it should not appear due to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION parameter but this warning always "pops".

A few things about the context:

- this part of code is just for testing, the whole code is in a class called for a lot of things and I cannot just don't log PHP Warnings
- in production context we just have the PHP Warning (not the stack trace)
- code is running in PHP v7.0 on Linux server
- I don't want to use the `@` to hide Warnings

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your exception gets caught ok but you need to change your settings with regards to error display:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

You can also set this in php.ini

Comment: Hello @Kasia, this could be an option (a little bit better than using the @ symbol) but really I'd like to use a "clean" option that's to say not just hide the warning but avoid it (and normally warnings should not be displayed when error mode is set to Exception). In fact this part of code runs in a very sensitive context that doesn't permit to hide warnings

Comment: on prod server you probably want to pipe your errors into log files anyway so this would still do it, but just not show it in browser. Either way I hope you find what you need :)

Comment: You're right ;) that's a little bit complex and it's for a back office script running in CLI but you're right.